# Discordjs - Create channel with fs.watchFile event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my bot to create a channel when an `fs.watchFile` event get trigered.

Here's the code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
//1000 lines of code here
const banLogFile = "logs/banlist_info.log";
fs.watchFile(banLogFile, (curr, prev) => {
        fs.readFile(banLogFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            // Parsing the new line in the file.
            const banSendPubAdmin = {} //embed here, I cut the details
            const baname2 = 'br-' + banName // Name of the channel + banned player name
            guild.channels //ISSUE IS HERE
                .create(baname2, {
                    type: 'text',
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: 'config.AdminRoleId',
                            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                        },
                    ]
                })           
                .then((channelBanReview) => {
                    const categoryId = '793625324927057982'
                    channelBanReview.setParent(config.BanReviewCategoryId)
                    client.channels.cache.get(channelBanReview.id).send({ embed: banSendPubAdmin });
                })
            
        });
});
//Another 500 lines of codes here too
client.login(config.token)
```

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` and some other similar undefined issues when the event is triggered.

I've tried many variation of the `.create` line with no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: where do you put value to "guild" var ??

Comment: let me your guild id please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after many hours of bashing my head on my keyboard.

To create a channel you need the guild information first.
Vast majority of the time people does that with chat commands, which store all the needed information required with the message.

But when creating a channel without discord events you have to define your guild.
I did try that before but forgot the `s` with `guilds`.

Here's the line that fixed my issue.

`client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID here').channels.create().then()`

Comment: Will be leave this here, since I haven't found anyone with the same question before.

Will accept after the 2 day delay.